# How do I "discover" Google's Provisioning API?

Tags: ruby, google-api, google-apps, google-provisioning-api, google-api-ruby-client

I'm using the (alpha) Ruby [`google-api-client`](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-ruby-client/) to interact with various services for our organization's Google Apps instance.

I'd like to discover the [**provisioning services**](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/provisioning/) API, authenticate a user with a service account, and update their password.

So far...

```
require 'google/api_client'

class GoogleProvisioningConnection
  def initialize(user_email=nil)
    @client = Google::APIClient.new
    @provisioning = @client.discovered_api('???', 'v2') # what's it called? user?

    key_file_name = 'mykey-privatekey.p12'
    key = Google::APIClient::PKCS12.load_key(key_file_name, 'notasecret')

    asserter = Google::APIClient::JWTAsserter.new(
      '...@developer.gserviceaccount.com',
      '???', # which url allows me access to their user?
    key)

    @client.authorization = asserter.authorize(user_email)
  end

end
```

Which string is used with `@client.discovered_api` to get at the provisioning API?
And when the JWT asserter is used, which service url should be requested?
Thanks

Comment: Perhaps there is a better way to go about this. Without a "Service Account"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Provisioning API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/provisioning/) uses the old gdata protocol. It won't work with the new discovery based libraries.

You should use [the GData Ruby Library](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-ruby-util/).